# AWS Load Balance not resolving to EC2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created an Ubuntu EC2 instance, and created a load balancer to point to that EC2 instance. The rules on the Listener for the load balancer look OK (ports 80 and 443). I can access the EC2 instance Apache2 HTTPD server in a Browser using the EC2 IP address and Domain (only port 80 is working, no HTTPS).

The inbound rules for the security group look OK, i.e. port 80 and port 443.

The health check is checking the server every 30 seconds, and is showing as healthy every time.

The main problem is that when I try to connect to the webserver in a browser using the DNS name for the load balancer, the page times out, and I do not see the request hit the Apache2 server logs. However, I can connect when using the EC2 instance domain name, and I also see the request hitting the Apache2 server logs.

I wondered if I could please ask if anyone else has had the same issue with the load balancer DNS name not resolving to the EC2 instance?

Many thanks,

Martin

EDIT: This was resolved by setting the correct security group.

Comment: Do you see logs on your web server of the health check request from the ELB?

Comment: Yes, every 30 seconds:

"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 250 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1800 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"

Comment: Please add your load balancer listener configuration, and target group configuration, to your question. Also, what about the security group assigned to the load balancer?

Comment: Load balancer is configured to point to two listeners: First points to port 80 of the EC2 instance, and is green for healthy. I believe this is what I see in my apache2 logs.

The second points to port 443 of my EC2 instance, and also shows green for healthy.

Comment: Closing down as resolved - issue with security group not being selected.

Thanks.